# String with literal unicode value to unicode character in Rust

Tags: rust

So i have a string for example like

```
"HITMAN\u2122 Free Trial"
```

is there any way i can convert the \u2122 to an actual unicode character so that the string would look like this

```
"HITMAN™ Free Trial"
```

Edit: for clarification the first string is an utf-8 string from an api, and i need to parse it for display

Comment: You mean, how to represent `"HITMAN™ Free Trial"` in source code using the `\u` escape or convert `"HITMAN\\u2122 Free Trial"` at runtime?

Comment: Convert at runtime to the unicode version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first encoding is the one you find in many languages, and for example in JSON. It differs from Rust literals in which you have `\u{2122}` instead of `\u2122`.

This gives us a solution: parse it as JSON.

```rust
let s = "HITMAN\\u2122 Free Trial";
let s: String = serde_json::from_str(&format!("\"{}\"", s)).unwrap();
assert_eq!(
    s,
    "HITMAN™ Free Trial",
);
```

But while this is useful as validation, you probably don't want to include a deserializer just for this, so you probably want to do the parsing yourself, for example with a regular expression:

```rust
use lazy_regex::*;

let s = "HITMAN\\u2122 Free Trial";
let s = regex_replace_all!(r#"\\u(\d{4})"#, s, |_, num: &str| {
    let num: u32 = u32::from_str_radix(num, 16).unwrap();
    let c: char = std::char::from_u32(num).unwrap();
    c.to_string()
});
assert_eq!(
    s,
    "HITMAN™ Free Trial",
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add `{`and`}` around 2122, like this:

```rust
let unicode_str = "HITMAN\u{2122} Free Trial";
println!("{}", unicode_str);
```

Comment: Sorry i was bit unclear, I added some clarification.